# How do I mock a function that calls an API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a component with a button that triggers a function and does a API call.

```js
// MainPage.tsx
exṕort const MainPage: FC () = () => {
const [hasApiError, setHasApiError] = useState<boolean>(false)

if (hasApiError){
  <ErrorPage/>
}

  return <PageWithForm submitHandler=submitHandler(setHasApiError)>
}
```

```js
// PageWithForm/PageWithFormServices.tsx
export const submitHandler = 
  (
  setHasApiError: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
  ): SubmitHandler<FormData> => async (data: FormData) => {
    try {
      const response = await callApiAndSendForm(data)
      // calls another function ...
    }catch(error){
      setHasApiError(true)
    }
  }
```

```js
// services/callApiAndSendForm.ts
export const callApiAndSendForm = async (data: FormData): Promise<ResponsesFromApi> =>
  fetch('/api/...', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then((res) => res.json())
```

I would like to be able to test if ErrorPage component is rendering correctly if the API call, submitHandler or anything is making hasApiError = true. I don't want to mock the setHasApiError inside of the component directly.

I tried to jest.mock the callApiAndSendForm by doing:

```js
const callApiAndSendFormMock = callApiAndSendForm as jest.Mock

// ... function to renderMainPage

it('should render ErrorPage if api call fails', async () => {
  callApiAndSendFormMock.mockRejectedValue('error')
  const { getById } = renderMainPage()  
  expect(getById('error-page').toBeVisible())

})
```

but it returns `TypeError: callApiAndSendForm.mockRejectedValue is not a function`

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't effect runtime at all. Using `as` is just lying to typescript that the type is different

Comment: So, ok! How can I test it without using jest.Mock? I also tried to mock.spy and it returned the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock `callApiAndSendForm` first, somewhere after imports in your test file:

```
//...
import { callApiAndSendForm } from 'services/callApiAndSendForm' 
//...
jest.mock('services/callApiAndSendForm')
//...
it('should render ErrorPage if api call fails', async () => {
  const callApiAndSendFormMock = callApiAndSendForm as jest.Mock
  callApiAndSendFormMock.mockRejectedValue('error')
  const { getById } = renderMainPage()  
  expect(getById('error-page').toBeVisible())
})
//...
```

Then it should work

Also you can provide implementation right in mock function:

```
jest.mock('services/callApiAndSendForm', () => ({
  callApiAndSendForm: () => Promise.reject('error'),
})
```

Comment: Omg, yes, I should have imported before doing as jest.Mock. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, sorry. Somehow it's rendering the <PageWithForm submitHandler=submitHandler(setHasApiError)> and not <ErrorPage/>. the getById (or any other getBy...) is returning error when it tries to get. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: That's very easy to fix, it depends on your react testing library if you are using test-utils see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html). Just wrap you render in async `act` function. If you are using react testing library just wrap your expect in `waitFor` see [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor)

Comment: So, it didn't work because I guess we need to render the component, simulate the form submission to change the state setHasApiError as false otherwise it won't work. Trying to mock the API will be useless because the button event hasn't been fired yet.

Comment: I'm trying to do that but have no idea how to :'( I'm very new to tests

Comment: No worries, you pull through it very soon! Firstly, what testing library you are using? (which library provide `getById` function?) Secondly, go to that library documentation and read how to fire event or simulate click. If you are still stuck I will be happy to assist you.